# In Xcode, how to suppress all warnings in specific source files?

Tags: xcode, warnings

In my application I use 3rd party code that triggers some warnings. I reviewed them and they can be safely ignored.

Now I want to "mark" a file somehow, so Xcode won't show any warnings for the code in that file.

How should I do that?

Answer (score 291, accepted):

Select your target and show Build Phases. Then enter the name of the file in the search box, and you should see it listed in the Compile Sources phase. Double-click in the Compiler Flags column for that file and enter `-w` to turn off all warnings for that file.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't solve the issue. I am still get warnings for the file. Should `-w` turn off all the warnings or just a subset of possible warnings?

Comment: Hmm, I expected `-w` to turn off all warnings, but perhaps the new compiler doesn't pay attention to that. In that case, turn off individual warnings. Find the warning in question in Build Settings, and show Quick Help in the Utilities view. You should see a description, with a `-Wname-of-warning` syntax. Prepend "no-" to the name and specify that in Compiler Flags. Example: to turn off `-Wunused-parameter` specify `-Wno-unused-parameter`

Comment: It turns out that all this is compiler-dependent. I mean, in one project that uses LLVM GCC compiler `-w` does the trick and in other project that uses plain GCC compiler `-Wno-name-of-warning` is the only way to go.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, also worked for me (`-w` and LLVM). Really handy when you include thirdparty files you don't wand to modify.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18883726/how-to-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-xcode-5 if you cannot find the "Compiler Flags" column.

Comment: Can't really do this for autogenerated code. I would have to do it for hundreds of files, which could change their name when they get autogenerated again.

Comment: @Zammbi Since the code is auto-generated, fix it to generate code free of warnings. If you can't do that, auto-patch the Xcode project to set the compiler flag.

Comment: I'm going to give this a try (additional target): http://stackoverflow.com/a/7535475/515455

Comment: If you have multiple targets and a file is included in more than one target, you must add the flag to each targets "Compile Sources" phase!

Comment: Does not work with Swift 2 using Xcode 7.0 and Apple LLVM 7.0

Comment: What if the libraries are static? I only have a thirdPartyLibraryFile.a under the "Build Phases" > "Link Binary With Libraries". There is no compiler flags option under that section.

Comment: @jotaEsse This flag suppresses compiler warnings, not linker warnings.

Comment: @JonReid Thank you. Do you know if it is possible to suppress linker warnings from 3rd party Libraries then?

Comment: @jotaEsse I don't know — and would like to know! Suggest you open a question, and leave a forwarding link here.

Comment: @JonReid Suggestion taken. The question has been asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/43261876/2754958. Please feel free to edit it if it is unclear.

Comment: @JonReid how to set -w flag for folder ?

Comment: @a.masri I don't think there's a way to set a compiler directive on an entire folder.

Answer (score 6):

Select Project in left navigator and select target go to build phase and Put -w in Build Phase of target file. It will hide all compiler warnings
[image]

Comment: Does not work with Swift 2 using Xcode 7.0 and Apple LLVM 7.0

Comment: passing clang compiler flags to a foreign compiler doesn't work. quelle surprise...

google the warning flag for the swift compiler and add that instead.

Answer (score 5):

**This works for Xcode 10.2+ and Swift 5**

**Manual fix:**

Add `-w -Xanalyzer -analyzer-disable-all-checks` to the problematic file from Xcode > Project > Targets > Compile Sources > Double click the file where you want to turn off warnings.

**Cocoapods Fix:**

If you're trying to suppress warnings from a problematic pod, you can automatically suppress all warnings from the dependency with the `inhibit_warnings` flag in your [podfile](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#inhibit_all_warnings_bang):

```
pod 'Kingfisher', '~> 4.6', :inhibit_warnings => true
```

[image]