# Make Xcode ignore LLVM build warnings in 3rd party project

Tags: xcode, llvm

I have a third party project in my Xcode workspace (it's a dependency for my main project) and I want Xcode to ignore all build warnings from that third party project.

Preferably I'd like to ignore all build warnings for the Vendor/* group in my project since that's where I put all my third party code.

Possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, but only if you compile the third-party files in a separate target. This way, you can set different compiler flags.

Let's say your main target is an application. You defined your build settings, as well as the compiler warning flags.

Now you want to use some third-party sources. You import them into your project, but they generate warning. You could of course change your main target's settings, but I'm pretty sure you want to keep your own settings.

Simply create an additional target in your project, which is a static library.
Removes the third-party files from your main target, and add them to the library.

In your main target's build phases, link your application with the static library.

This way, you'll be able to use the third-party code in your application, while having different compiler settings for third-party code.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible on a per file basis, see the blog entry at http://blog.bluelightninglabs.com/2011/12/suppressing-xcode-warnings-on-a-per-file-basis/

To summarize: Use the compiler flags on the “Build phases” tab.

Answer (score 4):

Go to **Build Phases** > **Compile Sources**.  Optionally filter the list.  Select the ones you want to exclude and then double click in the blank area under the **Compiler Flags** column. Add **-w** and hit return:

[image: Adding compiler flag to Build Phase]

Comment: Unfortunately you can't filter by containing folder.

Answer (score 3):

if you are worried only about warning via inclusion, then you can wrap your include statements in this:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
 // in reality, you will likely need to disable *more* than Wmultichar
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wmultichar"
#include <TheirLibrary/include.h>
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

if you also want to disable the build warnings it generates, then you can use `-w` or  `GCC_WARN_INHIBIT_ALL_WARNINGS = YES` for the third party target which you link to or bundle.

ideally, you will file reports with the vendor if it is closed. if it is open, then maybe you should just patch it yourself.

Comment: It may work, but I personally think this is a bad option, as your code will become dependent to the Clang's pragmas...

Comment: @Macmade your answer details the second section of my answer. if you're linking to the library, *chances are* that you will want to also *use* it in your program at some point. how do propose disabling warnings generated by the 3rd party headers when they are included in your project? note that you can also wrap the `#pragma clang diagnostic`s in compiler checks (because some compilers will complain about unknown pragmas, if requested).

Comment: You're right, but if the warnings come from the header files, then I will try to look for another solution, as it may imply very crappy code... : )

Comment: @Macmade not necessarily. even apple's headers will produce warnings when compiled with the warning settings i use. you just don't see these warnings in your build transcripts (using recent releases of the compilers) because warnings originating from system headers are simply not emitted. things also get much more complicated with c++/objc++ extensions and programs, or even C libraries which use static functions in the headers.