# How to suppress header file warnings from an Xcode project

Tags: objective-c, xcode

When I build [UnzipKit](https://github.com/abbeycode/UnzipKit) in Xcode 7 beta 4, I'm getting a compiler warning in MiniZip's `ioapi.h` file. For example:

```
.../ioapi.h:22:9: warning: macro name is a reserved identifier [-Wreserved-id-macro]
#define _ZLIBIOAPI64_H
```

`ioapi.c` has many of its own warnings, so I compile it with `-Wno-everything` like so:

[image: Compile Sources build phase]

However, there is no "Compiler Flags" setting available for the headers:

[image: Headers build phase]

How can I silence the warning without modifying the source file? I'd rather not modify it, as it's an external dependency. I also don't want to turn it on for the whole project, because it's a useful warning for my own code.

Comment: Maybe you need to set Enable Modules in Build Settings to NO?

Comment: @Leo What would that help? I want modules turned on.

Answer (score 9):

I found my answer using this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7535436/2148757

I imagine your code would look like this:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Weverything"
#import "ioapi.h" //Hide a warning in this header because we don't want to change our dependencies
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

Edit:
I did not need to import the header file in our project where this worked, but I imported it anyway into the PrefixHeader.pch file to remove the warning.

Comment: But that requires modifying the source, which I'd rather not do (as mentioned in the question). None of my own code imports `ioapi.h` - it's only other MiniZip files. Also, this warning appears to have gone away at some point. I'm not seeing it now in Xcode 7.3.1.

Comment: @Dov I'm glad your warning went away, we know how that happens sometimes with Xcode. I will clarify my answer, but I did not have to import this in my own code. I did anyway, in the PrefixHeader.pch, and the warning went away.

Comment: Should be `-Weverything` (not `-Wno-everything`, as originally posted). Answer edited accordingly.