# Disabling warning in Xcode4.2 for a specific file

Tags: xcode, xcode4.2

I'm using SQLite3 in my app, and the standard .c file gives me 13 warnings `Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'ssize_t' (aka 'long') to 'int'`

I'm trying to get rid of it, so I went to build phases, selected sqlite3.c, and added the compiler flag: -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 per [In Xcode, how to suppress all warnings in specific source files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921884/xcode-4-how-to-suppress-all-warning-in-specific-source-file)'s recommendation.  But this doesn't work.  I still get those warnings.

How do I disable all warnings for the sqlite3.c file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If using Clang, which I believe is the default in 4.2, the "-w" flag should disable all warnings.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't disable them.  They still show up like a crazy ex.

Comment: @David Make sure you're using a lowercase w. I just tested it with sqlite3.c using both Clang and GCC in 4.2 and it suppresses all of the warnings for me.

Comment: yep, using lowercase -w.  Selected in Build Phases under compiler flags.

Comment: Durrrr.  You're right.  I had another target that wasn't set with -w which was giving the error.  Thanks!