# XCode warnings when 3rd parties forgot to remove debugging symbols

Tags: xcode, debugging

often when debugging with XCode3.2 a lot of warnings appear about missing object files in 3rd party things that I don't want to debug anyway. e.g.

warning: Could not find object file blah/blah/...
- no debug information available for blah/blah/...

Is there a way I can disable these errors?

Answer (score 0):

As detailed in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921884/xcode-4-how-to-suppress-all-warning-in-specific-source-file), head to your Build Phases and add the following to the specific file's 'Compiler flags' section, depending on which compiler you use:

- With LLVM GCC compiler add `-w`
- With plain GCC, you must add `-Wno-name-of-warning` for each warning you want to ignore (*name-of-warning* being replaced by the description of the warning given in Build Settings' Quick Help view)

Comment: hi adam! I can't seem to find a gcc warning that corresponds to this message in the xcode3 / gcc 4.2 - Warnings list. One thing i thought might work was to strip debug symbols from the 3rd party binaries that  cause all these errors