# How to disable ARC for a single file in Xcode 5?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

I recently downloaded Xcode 5, and it's now my primary IDE. However, I now need to disable Automatic Reference Counting for a single file in my project.

In Xcode 4, I went to the Build Phases tab under my target, and I could double click the on the right side of a row in the Compile Sources section, add `-fno-objc-arc` to the list of compiler flags, and be off.

In 5, however, the column seems to be unclickable:

[image]

So, how do I do this?

Comment: try press enter

Comment: @xlc No luck there either

Comment: I had a little popup appear by selecting the file (so it is blue) and pressing enter. It also worked by double-clicking on the file name.

Comment: What exact version is this? I'm running Xcode 5A1413 (from the App Store) and double click works for me. It worked for the GM (5A1412) build as well

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Well, I just tried and found that you must had dragged the window to a smaller width. You need to drag it back to show the `Compiler Flag` column:

[image]

Answer (score 14):

To fix the real issue rather than a GUI issue, select the file and **press ENTER**, then you can add the `-fno-objc-arc` compiler flag.

Comment: No luck with this approach either.

Comment: @Undo I just tested it and it worked fine with Xcode 5, maybe it's an issue with your version. That's all I can guess.

Answer (score 4):

You appear to be missing the right-hand column. On my install it looks like this:

[image]

Notice the 'Compiler Flags' column to the right of the 'Name' column.

Double-clicking anywhere on the row allows me to type into the flags as long as that column is on screen. Making my window sufficiently thin causes it to be invisible so the first thing I'd try is making your window super-wide, to see whether you can get a flags column.