# Link two seperate cocoa touch projects

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

i have this problem for a while now. I have iPhone project which was built with non ARC. And now somehow i need to add another smaller project to it, but that project was built with ARC. I have tried to copy files one by one, but ass soon as i was done, i got lots of ARC errors and some with Security.framework... Can someone help me? Or give me some ideas how should i proceed?

I have tried [this](http://iappexperience.com/post/23288195515/using-arc-enabled-code-in-your-non-arc-project) but it didnt solvet issius with ARC...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ARC is done at compile time. ARC-enabled source code files need to be compiled with ARC, non-ARC source files need to be compiled without. It is a s simple as that. ARC is nothing but syntactic sugar injected by the compiler.

I have had this problem with some third parties not entirely migrated to ARC. Just create a static library around these files.

You could also try to change the per-file compiler options (see this question: [How to disable ARC for a single file in Xcode 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18883726/how-to-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-xcode-5)), but I would recommend against it since it will just become a maintenance burden in the end.

And of course, if it is your source code and not some third party: Migrate it to ARC. It is worth it.

Comment: I understand that, but when i create static library and add files of project with ARC compiler doesn't even show the error, it says "failed" and thats it...

Comment: Sounds strange, but if you go to the "Log Navigator" tab (the rightmost one) and click on the lasted "Build" event. There you can see the entire compiler output. Maybe that will help you identify the problem.