How to prevent a root object from being deleted in C++/Objective-C
I have the following code in my C++/Objective-C app:
#import <YandexMobileAds/YandexMobileAds-Swift.h>

@class AdHook;

namespace MyApp
{
    class AdHolder
    {
    public:

        AdHolder(IosInterstitialAd* cpp_ad);

        AdHook* m_hook;
    };
}

using namespace MyApp;

@interface AdHook : NSObject <YMAInterstitialAdLoaderDelegate, YMAInterstitialAdDelegate>
{
    @public IosInterstitialAd* m_cppAd;

    @public YMAInterstitialAdLoader* m_loader;
    @public YMAInterstitialAd* m_interstitialAd;
}
@end

@implementation AdHook 

- (id)initFromCpp:(IosInterstitialAd *)cpp_ad
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        m_cppAd = cpp_ad;
        m_interstitialAd = nil;

        m_loader = [[YMAInterstitialAdLoader alloc]init];
        m_loader.delegate = self;
    }
    return self;
}

AdHolder::AdHolder(IosInterstitialAd* cpp_ad)
{
    [YMAMobileAds enableLogging];

    m_hook = [[AdHook alloc]initFromCpp:cpp_ad];
}

void SomeOtherClass::load()
{
    NSLog(@"IosInterstitialAd::load()");

    YMAAdRequestConfiguration* configuration = [[YMAAdRequestConfiguration alloc]initWithAdUnitID:@"demo-interstitial-yandex"];

    [m_holder->m_hook->m_loader loadAdWithRequestConfiguration:configuration];
}

I create an instance of AdHolder class in C++ code and AdHolder's constructor creates an instance of Objective-C class AdHook that in its turn crates its internal Objective-C objects.
But I do not understand well enough what is the lifetime of m_hook? And I suspect that it is deleted at some point, because when I try to access m_hook->m_interstitialAd from YMAInterstitialAdLoaderDelegate callback I get a wrong value and the app crashes.
Is m_hook a strong reference? If it is not how to make it strong?
EDIT1
Tried to randomly add retain call to various objects in my app and made the app work by adding retain call to AdHook::m_interstitialAd:
- (void)interstitialAdLoader:(YMAInterstitialAdLoader * _Nonnull)adLoader didLoad:(YMAInterstitialAd * _Nonnull)interstitialAd
{
    NSLog(@"IosInterstitialAd::YMAInterstitialAdLoader::didLoad, %@", interstitialAd);

    m_interstitialAd = [interstitialAd retain];
    m_interstitialAd.delegate = self;
}

at least my app stopped crashing when I access m_interstitialAd.
So the question probably is if AdHook::m_interstitialAd a strong reference?

Found some examples: https://developernote.com/2024/09/examples-of-c-objective-c-interop/. Can they help?

May be just turn on ARC?

@Cy-4AH yes, it was turned off, see the picture: https://developernote.com/2024/09/examples-of-c-objective-c-interop/#arcoff

If you turned off ARC then you need implement smart pointer functionality in your holders: retain new objects on assign and release old objects. And release objects in destructor. But I don't know reasons to not use ARC.

@Cy-4AH I do not use ARC, because there is QT Purchasing code in my project that does not use it and does [objc_object release] in destructors.

You can disable ARC for particular files and use #if __has_feature(objc_arc) to check is it on

@Cy-4AH yes, it is -fno-objc-arc compiler flag (https://stackoverflow.com/a/18883995/2394762)

The issue likely stems from m_hook not being a strong reference in your C++ class. In Objective-C/C++ interop, plain pointers don't imply ownership. To create a strong reference, modify your AdHolder class to use a pointer to a pointer (AdHook** m_hook;). In the constructor, allocate it with m_hook = new AdHook*; *m_hook = [[AdHook alloc] initFromCpp:cpp_ad];. Add a destructor to clean up: if (m_hook) { [*m_hook release]; delete m_hook; }. When accessing, use (*holder()->m_hook)->m_loader. This ensures the AdHook object isn't deallocated unexpectedly. Also, verify that the AdHolder instance itself remains valid when you're accessing m_hook, as its premature destruction could lead to crashes.

Could you explain, please, why does the reference become strong with AdHook**? What actually changes with this? We create additional C++ pointer, right? So it is C++ pointer to Objective-C pointer, right?

Sure, the AdHook** approach creates a strong reference by using C++ to manage an Objective-C pointer. It allocates C++-controlled memory to store the Objective-C pointer, preventing ARC from releasing the object. The Objective-C runtime sees this as a persistent reference. When you release in the C++ destructor, you free both the Objective-C object and C++-managed memory. This bridges C++ and Objective-C memory management, controlling the Objective-C object's lifetime.

AdHolder itself is a C++ controlled memory that stores the Objective-C pointer, right?
