# Clang warnings not being suppressed in third party library (Xcode)

Tags: c++, xcode, clang, suppress-warnings, jsoncpp

I'm using Xcode 6.3.2 to compile my application, which depends on JsonCpp. I would like to suppress the large number of warnings that this library generates so I've specified the path to the JsonCpp header using `-isystem` as advised in  the [Clang User Manual](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#controlling-diagnostics-in-system-headers)

> Controlling Diagnostics in System Headers
>
> Warnings are suppressed when they occur in system headers. By default,
>   an included file is treated as a system header if it is found in an
>   include path specified by -isystem, but this can be overridden in
>   several ways.

However, this does not seem to be working as the warnings are still generated. E.g.

```
json.cpp:352:44: Implicit conversion changes signedness: 'long' to 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long')
```

Is there something else I need to set/unset?

Comment: What warnings and why doesn't disabling specific warnings in the *Build Settings* affect every warning the compiler sees, regardless of where it comes from (i.e. why does it matter if it comes from a "system header")?

Comment: I don't want to disable warnings in my application code. Using `-isystem` to specify the path to the header treats it as a system header and suppresses any warnings. Or it should.

Comment: OK that makes sense, however you are getting an error in `json.cpp` but that's not a system header is it.  If you are compiling these source files then `-isystem` will have no effect.  I think you should be suppressing warnings in specific source files.  Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921884/in-xcode-how-to-suppress-all-warnings-in-specific-source-files) work in Xcode still?

Comment: Xcode should treat it as a system header if the path to it is defined by `isystem`.

Comment: maybe the keyword there is *included* file. The file name does not look like it's an included file, but a normal source file being compiled.

Comment: @planetmaker I see your point. Subtle.