# ios hide alert from 3rd party framework/library

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

I am using a 3rd party library in my ios application. I have a compiled file i.e., `".a"` file and the header files `".h"` given to me..

The solution here [In Xcode, how to suppress all warnings in specific source files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921884/in-xcode-how-to-suppress-all-warnings-in-specific-source-files) talks about clicking the **Compiler Flags** of the source files and setting  `-w` . This doesn't have anything to do with alerts I believe.
Also, I don't have source files with me..

So my question is, how do I remove/hide/disable UIAlertView or UIAlertController from a 3rd party library?

Is there a way to do set some value in `info.plist` or `AppDelegate.m` or anywhere in `Xcode`?

Comment: With UI alerts you mean something similar to UIAlertControllers? You don't. (And what does that have to do with a compiler warning?)

Comment: Yes.. UIAlertView or UIAlertController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone out there who is using libMobileVLCKit as their 3rd party framework, **use this**:

```
 _mediaplayer = [[VLCMediaPlayer alloc] initWithOptions:@[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@=%@",@"extraintf",@""]]];
```

instead of:

```
 _mediaplayer = [[VLCMediaPlayer alloc] init];
```

It won't display your VLC alert which includes:

```
"Your input can't be opened:
VLC is unable to open the MRL 'file:///somefile.mp4'. Check the log for details."
```