# Disable xcode warnings in gitlab logs

Tags: ios, xcode, gitlab

How can we disable printing Xcode warnings in GitLab? Log limit is exceeding and my job is failing every time as the warning for "using 'class' keyword for protocol inheritance is deprecated; use 'AnyObject' instead" is getting logged many times.

Comment: You can suppress specific warnings, [here's a guide](https://davedelong.com/blog/2018/12/15/silencing-specific-build-warnings/).

Comment: Why would you ever want to disable Xcode warnings?

Comment: Why don't you fix the warnings? You can fix them in a few minutes using search & replace.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Xcode, how to suppress all warnings in specific source files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921884/in-xcode-how-to-suppress-all-warnings-in-specific-source-files)

Comment: "Why would you ever want to suppress warnings": because in companies, you don't get free time to fix whatever bugs you. The team is aware of the issues, and it needs to get to the current errors, hidden from view by the many warnings planned for Soon(tm).

And "We'll just spend three weeks on cleaning the code then go back to features" isn't an option in real life.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling warnings won't fix your problem.

Yo can change the build log size of your jobs in Gitlab CI/CD so you can see the entire log and be able to view the real error.

To do that edit your config.toml file and add a new limit in kilobytes:

```
[[runners]]
  output_limit = 10000
```

For this to take effect, you need to restart the gitlab runner:

```
sudo gitlab-runner restart
```

Also check the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-runners-section)

Comment: While this may solve the fatal error OP is encountering in their GitLab job, this doesn't answer the principal question (which future viewers of this question are most likely to care about): "How can we disable printing Xcode warnings in GitLab?"